# Checking if one document has the contents of the other c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, search, comparison

I am writing a code to check to see if one document (text1.txt) contains a list of banned words (bannedwords.txt) in it.

For example, the text1 document contains lyrics to a song and i want to check whether the word pig from the banned document is included in it. I then want the out put to be similar to:

```
"pig" found 0 times
"ant" found 3 times
```

This is what I have come up with so far but cannot seem to put the array of banned words into the search. Any help would be amazing :D

Thanks Fitz

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool CheckWord(char* filename, char* search)
{
    int offset;
    string line;
    ifstream Myfile;
    Myfile.open(filename);

    if (Myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!Myfile.eof())
        {
            getline(Myfile, line);
            if ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "The Word  " << search<< " was found" << endl;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Not found";
            }
        }
        Myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open this file." << endl;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file("banned.txt");
    if (file.is_open())//file is opened
    {
        string bannedWords[8];//array is created

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            file >> bannedWords[i];
        }
    }
    else //file could not be opened
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }

    ifstream text1;//file is opened
    text1.open("text1.txt");

    if (!text1)//if file could not be opened
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }

    CheckWord("text1.txt", "cat");

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: We like clear questions.  What does "but cannot seem to put the array of banned words into the search" even mean?  Please give a clear example of some short input files and output, what's wrong and what you don't understand about why it happens.

Comment: Hints: `push_back()` to `std::vector<std::string> bannedWords;` instead of using a fixed size array, and created `bannedWords` outside the `if`/`for` constructors - otherwise it'll leave scope and be destroyed before you want to use it.  Pass it to `CheckWord` as an extra parameter.  After an unrecoverable error, call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` instead of printing an error message and trying to continue with bad data.  Use `while (getline(Myfile, line)` and do not test for `while (...eof)`.

Comment: is your question: "How can I change the call to CheckWord to pass an array of strings?".

Answer (score 0):

Your `main()` function is reading the contents of `banned.txt` into an array of 8 `std::string` named `bannedWords`.

The array `bannedWords` is not being used anywhere after that.   C++ doesn't work by magic, and compilers are not psychic so cannot read your mind in order to understand what you want your code to do.   If an array (or its elements) are not accessed anywhere, they will not be used to do what you want with them.

You need to pass strings from the `bannedWords` array to `CheckWord()`.  For example;

```
 CheckWord("text1.txt", bannedWords[0].c_str());
```

will attempt to pass the contents of the first string in `bannedWords` to `CheckWord()`.

However, that will not compile either unless you make the second parameter of `CheckWord()` (named `search`) be `const` qualified.

Or, better yet, change the type of the second argument to be of type `std::string`.    If you do that, you can eliminate the usage of `c_str()` in the above.

I don't claim that is a complete solution to your problem - because there are numerous problems in your code, some related to what you've asked about, and some not. However, my advice here will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague; it looks like you need to spend some time to pin down your program structure before you could ask for help here.
However, since we were all new once, here's a suggestion for a suitable structure:
*(I'm leaving out the file handling bits because they're irrelevant to the essential structure)*

```
//Populate your array of banned words
std::string bannedWords[8];
int i;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    file >> bannedWords[i];
}

//Load the entire file content into memory
std::ifstream in("text1.txt");
std::string fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

So now the entire file content is in the string "fileContents", and the 8 banned words are in "bannedWords". I suggest this approach because otherwise you're opening, reading, and closing the file for every word. Hardly a good design.

Now you've got to check each word against the file content. There's some more sophisticated ways to do this, but your simplest option is a loop.

```
//Loop through each banned word, and check if it's in the file
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (fileContents.find(bannedwords[i]) != std::string::npos)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }    
}
```

Obviously you'll need to do the find a little differently if you want to count the number of occurrences, but that's another question.